# The @ sign has swapped places with the " sign on my Macbook Pro keyboard

Tags: keyboard

The @ sign has swapped places with the " sign on my Macbook Pro keyboard.  How to I swap them back?

Comment: Have you changed keyboard layouts? Check your system preferences.

Comment: Control + space will allow you to switch the language. You must have two input configure.

Comment: You most likely  need to go to system prefs/keyboard/input sources and REMOVE the item named "British PC".  That is not right for a MacBook.  You should have only ONE item on the list, with the name "US", "ABC", or "British" to have @ at Shift 2 as printed on the keys.

Comment: I have managed to sort it now, thanks to all the really useful assistance from everyone.  THANK YOU

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to the Apple Menu (top left of your screen)
2. Click on "System Preferences"
3. Click on "Keyboard"
4. Choose "Input Sources"
5. Click on the "+" icon
6. Select layout name eg. British, US, or ABC  (NOT British PC, which has @ in the wrong place).
7. Click "Add"
8. Drag the desired input to the top of the list (drag and drop)

these steps may vary slightly depending on macOS version you have. Should it not be the same please tell us what macOS you have (eg. 10.13 or Mavericks...)

Comment: I am using 10.15.2 version and I get to keyboard but there is no input source option.  Really appreciate the help.

Comment: Hi @AlisonCattanach I don't have Catalina but here is the official guide from Apple: https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/type-language-mac-input-sources-mchlp1406/mac

Comment: I have followed instructions and changed it to British but it is still the same.  It is only the 2 things that have swapped. It happened after I wiped dust off the keyboard while it was still on!  Oops.

Comment: How did you clean the computer? Was there liquid involved?

Comment: changing from `British - PC` to `British` fixed that, but now that am typing this comment I realised that it also changes where the pipes \| and the tilda and backquote are `~